# Does IRS count paying mortgage principal as taxable income from family?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, gift-tax, gifts

My parents offered me a generous gift, specifically they want to pay off $10,000  of my mortgage principal (the mortgage is under my name, not theirs).

However, I am hesitant to let them do this, as I am worried that IRS will consider it a taxable gift and tax that amount.

Is that a valid worry? Or is it safe to let them pay $10,000?

Answer (score 28):

Gifts are not taxable income to the recipient.

In the US, gift tax is paid by the giver, not the recipient. However, there is an annual gift exclusion amount (currently $15,000/year). Any gifts under that amount are not taxable and don't need to be reported to the IRS. This limit is per person, so your parents could give you up to $30,000 and have no reporting requirement or gift-tax liability. If you are married that can double, because it's per recipient and per giver.

Even when the annual gift tax exclusion is exceeded, it doesn't necessarily mean there's gift tax owed, as there's also a lifetime exemption, but amounts above the annual limit are required to be reported and either gift tax is owed or the excess counts toward the lifetime exemption.

Comment: And of course they could each give you $15K today, and another $15K in a couple of weeks :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Just make sure you read this comment near the end of the year as the exemption is annual. 

Comment: @Ian MacDonald: Yes, comments have dates on them :-)

Answer (score 7):

Highlights from [an IRS.com article](https://www.irs.com/articles/7-things-you-should-know-about-gift-tax), "Here are 7 things you should know about the Federal gift tax":

**1. Gifts to Family Members Count**

> The gift tax and exclusion limit (below) apply whether you are making
>   the gift to a complete stranger, a nephew, or your own children. The
>   only person you can give a gift to that is exempt from the gift tax is
>   your spouse. Gifts to your spouse qualify for the marital deduction.

**2. There Is an Annual Gift Tax Exclusion**

> You do not have to pay tax on gifts that are less than the annual
>   exclusion limit, which generally changes every year. Currently, the
>   annual exclusion is $15,000 per recipient. In other words, you can
>   give up to $15,000 to each of your children this year without having
>   to pay any gift tax.

**5. Married Couples Can Give Twice As Much**

> Spouses can each give up to $15,000 to the same recipient and still
>   stay within the annual exclusion threshold. Together, a married couple
>   can give $30,000 to each donee without incurring the gift tax. Most
>   tax professionals recommend that married couples give money in the
>   form of 2 separate checks, each signed by one of the spouses, to avoid
>   any confusion.

Comment: I was dismayed that an article from the IRS would use the phrase “Most tax professionals recommend...”. Then I realized that this article is on irs.com, not irs.gov. (You might want to make that clear in the answer.)

Comment: Perhaps it is worth pointing out that Christmas and birthday presents are also counted as gifts, and so if you cut a check for $15000 to your Number One Son today (two days before Christmas), you will likely exceed the exempted amount if you have already mailed him a Christmas or birthday present.

Comment: @prl - So you're dismayed bt the sentence: "MOST TAX PROFESSIONALS RECOMMEND that married couples give money in the form of 2 separate checks, each signed by one of the spouses, to avoid any confusion"?  Do you think that if one parent gave a child $30k instead of each parent giving $15k each that the IRS would accept it as within the $15k per person gift limit?  I don't get why you have a complaint that this info  comes from irs.com rather than  irs.gov.  Of the  information that I posted from the irs.com site, what part of it do you believe is misleading or  incorrect?

Comment: @BobBaerker, ...I don't read the objection to be that the content itself is misleading or incorrect, simply that it's *less authoritative* than an irs.gov source. And the opening to the answer describing its information as directly drawn from "an IRS article" when the linked source isn't directly published by the IRS itself is indeed a bit misleading.

Comment: @Charles, Yes, that’s exactly what I meant. That phrase was what clued me into the fact that this is *not* from an IRS publication.

Comment: Bob, Form 709 explicitly allows splitting gifts of more than $15k given by one spouse to use the exclusion of both spouses. (The cynic in me might suggest that tax professionals make that recommendation because it requires a gift tax form for each spouse rather than only one, so they get to charge more.)

Comment: @prl You should not be so cynical!  If a gift of $30k or less from one spouse is split equally on a Form 709 filed by that spouse, the other spouse does not need to file a Form 709 at all, does s/he? The tax professionals are shooting themselves in their feet by suggesting that the spouses give $15k each in which case _no_ Forms 709 need be filed at all and so the tax professionals get to charge nothing, as opposed to telling the spouses to send only one check for $30k to be signed by one spouse only, so that at least one, and maybe two, Forms 709 must be filed: more charges for services!

Comment: Oh, of course you’re right, @Dilip.

Comment: I think irs.com has given decent advice in this case. If the money comes from a non-joint account, it counts as a gift from the account owner only. Then if you give over $15k you have to file form 709 either way: to count it against your lifetime exclusion, or for your spouse to consent to it counting against their annual exclusion. Form 709 is much harder than writing a second check

Comment: It's a head scratcher to make a fuss and conclude that  the same advice coming from IRS.COM is less authoritative than coming from IRS.GOV